# Why do the Cromulons look like Rick?

Tags: rick-and-morty

In "Get Schwifty" ([S2 Ep5](https://rickandmorty.fandom.com/wiki/Get_Schwifty)), a group of giant floating heads known as Cromulons come to Earth to host their intergalactic reality television show.

What always struck me as odd about the Cromulons is how much they look like Rick Sanchez.

**Is there a reason why the Cromulons look and sound like Rick? Or is it just a coincidence?**

[image: Cromulon]
[image: Rick]

Comment: They hardly look like him at all. The mouth and the unibrow are literally the only similarities. I'm gonna give the eyes a pass since everyone has the same eyes, but the nose, the ears (or lack of), the shape of the head, the hair (or lack of), the brow ridges (or lack of), the complexion are all different. They look nothing alike. And their voices are only similar in that they are voiced by the same actor, but that actor is very clearly using different a deeper, slower, less drunken voice for the cromulons than for Rick.

Comment: Is it a coincidence, or just an animation style?

Comment: @JDoe Can you make that an answer?

Comment: Note that Jerry has a similar mouth as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It's just the animation style.

The only similarities you see are due to artistic style, intrinsic to the cartoon, not to the individual characters. If you compare facial characteristics, there are few similarities. The eyes are the same only because every character in the cartoon has the same eyes. The mouth and unibrow look similar but the cromulon's face is wider so everything is a bit wider, the length of the mouth and unibrow, and the distance between the eyes. The nose, the ears (or lack of), the shape of the head, the hair (or lack of), the brow ridges (or lack of), the complexion are all different.

And their voices are only similar in that they are voiced by the same actor, but that actor is very clearly using different a deeper, slower, less drunken voice for the cromulons than for Rick.